# Eigen rowwise operation based on an index vector

Tags: eigen

Suppose I want to subtract an element row-wise positioned by a given index vector in C++ Eigen, what are the best and the most efficient way to do this?

```
  // D: an Eigen::MatrixXf, L: an Eigen::VectorXi
  // D.rows() == L.rows()
  // 0 <= L(i) < D.cols()

  for(int i=0; i<D.rows(); ++i) D(i, L(i)) -= 1;
```

Is there any internal expression for me to do this without writing an explicit loop? Here minus one is just an example. Ideally, I want to change the value of `D(i, L(i))`.

Comment: As of yet, indexing with a vector is not supported. I seem to remember ggael (I think) mentioning something about a module in the unsupported part. Try looking there.

Comment: The devel branch support array of indices as in matlab, but here the problem is slightly different because it consists in picking one element within each row. There is nothing better than a for loop for now.